# How to fix scope problem inside "then" function react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to print out of Printer. I am a little new to react and javascript. I am trying to pass the state to a then function of Third Party Code. But i am getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'restaurant_name' of undefined
```

How can i pass `state` to the scope of `then` function of `qz`?

```
print = () => {
    let { state } = this.state;
    qz.websocket.connect()
    .then(function() {
     return qz.printers.find("BillPrinter");
   }).then(function(printer) {
         var config = qz.configs.create(printer);
         var data = [
              `${state.restaurant_name}` + '\x0A',
              `${state.restaurant_address}`
         ]

         return qz.print(config, data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Try this tip: ```function(printer) {``` to ```printer => {```. This is one of the ES6 features for binding `this` to the nested functions.

Comment: let { state } = this.state; should be  let state  = this.state;

Comment: Voting to close as the problem was caused by a typo (the variable was improperly assigned a value, it has nothing to do with scope)

Comment: @AliTorki — The function doesn't use `this`!

Comment: Bind `this` to the print function in your onClick event or anything else via `this.print.bind(this)` and after that, you have access to `this` and maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some unnecessary destructuring that is causing your error - `this.state.state` doesn't exist, yet this line:

```
let { state } = this.state;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
let state = this.state.state;
```

Remove the curly braces and it'll work fine.

```
let state = this.state;
```

Also note that `state` will be a reference to `this.state` rather than being another object.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function to keep the function in the upper scope as [@Ali Torki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56848063/how-to-fix-scope-problem-inside-then-function-react#comment100246898_56848063) suggested:

```
.then(printer => {....})
```